# How do I install a package (consisting of .h and .lib .dll) with CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake, dll, lib, vcpkg

I was provided a package which was released with `.h` `.dll` and `.lib`. Now, I'm trying to integrate this package into my cpp project with CMake.

I came along using the packetmanager vcpkg, so I tried adding this package to vcpkg by creating a port. Essentially, this port checks out a GitHub repository with `vcpkg_from_github` and installs the library with `vcpkg_cmake_install`.

So I created a GitHub repo containing only the `.h` `.dll` and `.lib` and a `CMakeLists.txt`, which (from my understanding) should install the binary and include files of the repository the moment `vcpkg_cmake_install` is called.

Now my question is what this `CMakeLists.txt` should look like.
My arbitary try of this `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.17)
project(medit-libs CXX)  

add_library(pcanbasic STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(pcanbasic PROPERTIES
    IMPORTED_LOCATION "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/lib/PCANBasic.lib"
)

target_include_directories(pcanbasic INTERFACE "{CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/include")

include(GNUInstallDirs)

install(TARGETS pcanbasic
    EXPORT pcanbasic-targets
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
    INCLUDES DESTINATION include
)
install(EXPORT pcanbasic-targets
    FILE pcanbasic-targets.cmake
    NAMESPACE pcanbasic::
    DESTINATION lib/cmake/pcanbasic 
)
install(FILES pcanbasic.h
    DESTINATION include
)
```

failed.

Can anyone tell me

1. if the approach I'm doing to integrate the library into my external project is correct/optimal
2. what the `CMakeLists.txt` should actually look like?

I'm also happy to take other solutions integrating my library files into a CMake managed project.

Comment: 90% sure your approach is wrong, but also I am not entirely sure what you are trying to do. If you would like to use 3rd-party precompiled library in your project, create `Find<package>.cmake` and place it under your (preferably) `ROOT/cmake` directory. Then just find it with `find_package` and use in your project, it depends on you if you will create imported library or just define some `FOO_INCLUDE_DIRS` variables. If you are an owner of that library and want to make it installable and discoverable by your other projects, follow cmake documentation.

Comment: [From this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20746936/what-use-is-find-package-when-you-need-to-specify-cmake-module-path) Module mode. Here [how to create package with cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55635294/how-to-create-packages-with-cmake). [Solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20833226/library-headers-and-define/20838147#20838147) from that answer shows how to nicely export all of your package info like include dirs, compiler options etc.

Comment: "I'm also happy to take other solutions integrating my library files into a CMake managed project." -- [FetchContent](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FetchContent.html) also worth a look. Easier than getting your package into vcpkg.

Comment: @pptaszni what I've tried to do in the first place was getting my libs from a vcpkg port, which I created following this guide: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/registries-bring-your-own-libraries-to-vcpkg/ . Essentially, in a file called `portfile.cmake` the library is build/installed by calling `vcpkg_cmake_install`. What I've been confused with is, that I want to use precompiled library files (.lib .dll) and .h, which is why this approach is challanging to me.

Comment: @pptaszni anyways, creating a `Find<package>.cmake` file seems a lot more intuitive, since I was provided with a 3rd-party precompiled library.

Comment: @pptaszni I still wonder if there is any install commands missing. `find_package` worked and `target_link_libraries` also didnt throw an error. Yet the build failed due to x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lpcanbasic: No such file or directory. (pcanbasic being the package I refer to)

Comment: Try to edit the question with your modified `CMakeLists.txt`, new `FindPcanbasic.cmake`, and the project directory layout, and we'll see.